# Rolling take off compared to take off from a standstill

Tags: engine

When ever I fly I choose flights with the most take off and landings. After going down the taxiway and turning onto the runway sometimes the flight crew ramp up the engines up while holding the airplane from moving with the brakes, then let off the brakes and the plane shoots down the runway like a rocket sled on on wheels. Other times the plane will go down the taxiway, turn onto the runway and without stopping ramp up the engines and head down the runway. What is the difference in these two techniques? Is it pilot choice?

Comment: Boeing recommends a rolling takeoff for setting takeoff thrust. It 
expedites takeoff and reduces the risk of foreign object damage or 
engine surge/stall due to a crosswind. The change in takeoff roll 
due to the rolling takeoff procedure is NEGLIGIBLE when compared to 
a standing takeoff.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that may be going on.

Generally the foot on the breaks, full throttle, spool up, release and roll is derivative of a [short field takeoff.](https://www.firstflight.com/private-pilot-course/advanced-takeoff-and-landing-techniques/) In other words you need all available runway and all available power to get off the ground safely and clear your runway end obstacles. This is dictated by airplane performance and runway conditions/length.

Roll on, roll into full throttle and go is more or less standard. In some cases this may follow an ATC clearance like

> 123AB Cleared for takeoff 22 depart no delay

This generally means there is either someone inbound for a landing but theres time for you to go, or there is a long queue on the ground and the controller wants you to get going. Stopping on the runway to spool up your engines takes *time* and at a busy field that can be in short supply.

Its important to note that in any case the pilot should line the aircraft up with centerline prior to applying full throttle.

The aircraft can also be instructed to, ["line up and wait"](https://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/news/current_events/lauw/) in which case its cleared to enter the runway and wait on the numbers until cleared. This may occur at an airport that offers parallel runway operations and the aircraft is waiting for a plane to land on a parallel runway.

---

EDIT: I found a possible dupe, noted in the comments. Its a bit different so ill leave this answer here and let the community decide.

Answer (score 0):

before takeoff, the pilot knows the handbook values for balanced runway length for any density altitude, the gross weight of the plane, and the runway length available. If there is far more runway length available than the handbook requires, then upon being cleared the pilot may elect to roll on, start the run, and go to full power. If not, the pilot should instead roll into position, stand on the brakes, spool up the engines, check gauges for full power, release brakes and roll.

Of course, ATC has the final say, and as pointed out by Dave, may specifically instruct the pilot to do one thing or the other depending on what's required.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the takeoff procedure being employed as well as the aircraft type.  Rolling takeoffs are a preferred procedure for soft field takeoffs on grass strips which may have high grass or wet sod and the aircraft is kept rolling to prevent the possibility of the landing gear becoming stuck in the muck.  Short field takeoffs involve lining the aircraft up on centerline as close to the threshold edge as possible, applying brake pressure while running the engines to full power, thence releasing the brakes and commence the takeoff roll.  This is done to miminimze the amount of runway needed to perform the takeoff roll on.  Multi engine airplanes will use the same technique in order to conform with manufacturer performance data on accelerate-stop and accelerate-go distances, which are a necessary performance metric to have established as part of the pre-takeoff brief for emergency contingencies in the event of an engine failure.  This is the standard takeoff procedure when flying multi engine aircraft.

In the case of most airliners and civil jets in general, they will usually hold brakes and establish 60% or so of the selected takeoff thrust in order to accomplish a final check on the engines, then release brakes and increase to takeoff thrust.  A pilot may opt to hold brakes and throttle to takeoff thrust first then begin the takeoff roll.  As for rolling takeoffs, one could argue it’s sloppy airmanship but plenty of fleet pilots do it on a regular basis.